# STM32 Using TIMer to break loop

Tags: c, stm32

### So I've initialized a timer which I want to count for 100

main section where stm32 works.

```
#include "stm32l0xx.h"

#define SYSCLK_FREQ 131072

void timer_tick(uint16_t n_ms);

int main(void)
{
    TIM6->PSC = (SYSCLK_FREQ/1000)-1; //100us   
    TIM6->CR1 = TIM_CR1_CEN | TIM_CR1_OPM; //one-pulse mode
    TIM6->EGR = TIM_EGR_UG; //generate update
    TIM6->SR=0; //clear update - after few instructions
...
}
```

---

first time I am using the timer there, its declared right after main

```
void delay(uint16_t n_ms)
{
    //upcounting timer - 16bit
    TIM6->CNT = 65535-n_ms;
    TIM6->CR1 = TIM_CR1_CEN | TIM_CR1_OPM; //one-pulse mode
    while(!(TIM6->SR & TIM_SR_UIF)); //wait
    TIM6->SR = 0;   
}
```

---

than Iam using the same timer (becouse I have only TIM3 which I cannot interupt and TIM6 used only for delay function)

```
void timer_tick(uint16_t n_ms)
{
    //upcounting timer - 16bit
    TIM6->CNT = 65535-n_ms;
    TIM6->CR1 = TIM_CR1_CEN | TIM_CR1_OPM; //one-pulse mode
    TIM6->ARR = n_ms-1; // Auto reload value 
    TIM6->CCR1 = n_ms; // Start PWM duty for channel 3 
    //TIM6->CCR2 = n_ms; // Start PWM duty for channel 4 
    TIM6->CCMR1 = TIM_CCMR1_OC1M_2 | TIM_CCMR1_OC1M_1 | TIM_CCMR1_OC2M_2 | TIM_CCMR1_OC2M_1;  // PWM mode on channel 1 & 2 
    TIM6->CCER = TIM_CCER_CC1E | TIM_CCER_CC2E; // Enable compare on channel 1 & 2 
    TIM6->DIER = TIM_DIER_UIE; // Enable TIM6 interrupt
    TIM6->SR = 0;   
}
```

---

And here working on interupt. Iam calling the function to start the clock counting to 100 (Iam assuiming its right) than interuption realising switch that can work only 100 ms - after its gotta stop working on it and break the loop.

```
void USART1_IRQHandler(void)
{
    static enum {00, 01, 02, 03, CRC} next_frame = 00; // frame construction

    if(!sending_flag) //half-duplex
    {
        if(USART1->ISR&USART_ISR_FE) //frame error check&clear
            USART1->ICR = USART_ICR_FECF;
        else
        timer_tick(100);
        do {
            switch(next_frame)
            {
                case 00:{ DOSTUFF; next_frame=01; break; } //starting marker
                case 01:{ DOSTUFF; next_frame=02; break; } 
                case 02:{ DOSTUFF; next_frame=03; break; } 
                case 03:{ DOSTUFF; next_frame=CRC; break; } 
                case CRC:{ TIM6->SR = ~TIM_SR_CC2IF; break; } // clear flag
                default: break; 
            }   
        } while (!(TIM6->SR&TIM_SR_CC2IF)); //TIM_SR_UIF
    }

    if(USART1->ISR & USART_ISR_TC)
    {
        USART1->ICR = USART_ICR_TCCF;
        GPIOA->BSRR = GPIO_BSRR_BR_11 | GPIO_BSRR_BR_12;
        sending_flag=0;
    }
}
```

---

I dont realy understend [documentation](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/63/3c/c0/51/1c/fb/44/d4/DM00108281.pdf/files/DM00108281.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00108281.pdf) of my STM about the timers. 
Having this line set like that `TIM6->CCR1 = n_ms; // Start PWM duty for channel 3` Iam assuming there should be a flag at `TIM6->SR&TIM_SR_CC2IF` after timer reach `TIM6->ARR = n_ms-1; // Auto reload value`
After adding this `do while` loop my STM stopped responding and Iam not able to debug it.

---

- Is the counter set right?
- Can I use declared timer twice and call it like I do?

Comment: Why don't you use just STM32 hal libraries? Or just STM32CubeMX? Have you enabled timer peripheral clock, smth like `__HAL_RCC_TIM6_CLK_ENABLE()` ? By creating your own hal libraries you are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @KamilCuk those low level `__HAL..`  are ok but the HAL itself is rubbish

Comment: I am not using HAL till now and for so short modification I don't want to implement new libs :) // It cannot be done on normal TIMers?

Comment: Do not be offended, but (IMO) your algorithm is extremely bad and actually I do not see any way to improve it except writing a new better code.

Comment: I am not, I've been considering it my self. How would you try to interrupt switch after 100ms if the program hangs on receiving frame? I've been thinking about interruptions it selves but If I am not gonna find a better solution than the one I am working on I will just check if the bit is a starting marker and by that start reading frame over.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the counter set right?

Not really. There are a lot of problems in your timer configuration, lets try to spot some of them:

```
#define SYSCLK_FREQ 131072
TIM6->PSC = (SYSCLK_FREQ/1000)-1; //100us
```

1. Timer is connected to some APB bus (1 or 2), which can be also
   divided. If You set new APB divider value, your timer will no longer
   work as you would expect.
2. Clock frequency = 131072 ? Independent of unit, you will not achieve 100us period by dividing it by 1000.

   `void delay(uint16_t n_ms)
   {
       //upcounting timer - 16bit
       TIM6->CNT = 65535-n_ms;
       TIM6->CR1 = TIM_CR1_CEN | TIM_CR1_OPM; //one-pulse mode
       while(!(TIM6->SR & TIM_SR_UIF)); //wait
       TIM6->SR = 0;
   }`

This is not the way you use timer. If you want to measure some time, just set ARR to right value and start the counter.

Your `timer_tick(uint16_t n_ms)` is totaly wrong. Counter is upcounting from 0 to ARR value, then stops (if one pulse mode is set).  Firstly, set all the timer configuration registers, then start the counter. If you start the counter, then modify ARR, CCRX or other registers, you can be 100% sure, that timer will fall.

Comment: Right, thank you for your time. That helped me a little with understanding how the TIMers works. There is a copy/paste mistake in the time comment. This clock counts in milliseconds. The delay itself you saying is built wrong but It does hold the program for the designed time, is it a bad habit to do it like that?